# mobile PIN based authentication for mobile app

Tags: flutter, azure, react-native, spring-security

I need to build a mobile app where i need to first register a user by phone number followed by setting up a 4 digit PIN. Next time when user logs in user can directly input the set 4 digit PIN and logs in on the app.
How can i implement it with spring security?
My thought is, when user registers with his/her phone no + PIN then do i need to keep this combination in Spring token store or an IDP like keycloack so that when user opens the app again then i can do a check in db if the device is registered in the db (with IMEA no) with mpin set up then show the PIN screen to input? In this case, will PIN be a part of IDP then which field in IDP should hold PIN? like password or something..?
can you pls give me some direction around this.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter package :

```
local_auth 2.1.7
```

The authenticate() method uses biometric authentication, but also allows users to use pin, pattern, or passcode.

Comment: Hi @rowApps, Thanks for your response. Yes, flutter can use PIN based login but my query is more towards the identity provider? how can i set up an identity of such user who registered with his phone number. Do you suggest to use Keycloack where user can be created with phone number as userid and PIN as a Password or a custom attribute..
My only curiosity is to understand, how should i set up an identity provider like Keycloack/Azure AD for mobile PIN..